# BIOS Settings changed

Tags: boot, uefi

The option Secure Boot in the BIOS has changed from deactivated to activated and the OS could not boot anymore. Two days ago was a boot loader update and an old Linux kernel was removed.

The user could not have accidentally opened BIOS and changed the settings. It's an Lenovo notebook running Ubuntu 18.04.

What could have caused the changed BIOS settings?

Comment: If you did a major Windows update, that will often reset UEFI settings. Or if you do a UEFI firmware update, that resets everything to defaults. I have to keep a list of the changes I normally make in UEFI, so when updating I can easily reset them.

Comment: Two days before the problem occurred I find infos in the update log: generated grub config and added boot entry for efi firmware. the computer was restarted a few times since then without problems. Indeed, there was a windows 10 update (perhaps the october update). Is Ubuntu or GRUB able to change BIOS settings?

Comment: Grub will update UEFI boot entries to add Ubuntu entry. Windows has tools to update UEFI from inside Windows, not sure when or if it does it. Linux now also has a new tool to update UEFI with Ubuntu updates. Only some brands supported now. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist & 
https://fwupd.org/vendorlist One user did post that it updated UEFI and he did not know it.